# How can I recover deleted calendar events?

Tags: calendar, data-recovery

I had duplicate events from syncing so I deleted what I thought were the correct set but it turns out I deleted the ones from my Outlook calendar which in turn deleted them from my Outlook calendar during the sync.  How can I recover them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to recover these.. Only if you should have backups of your Outlook calendar, but I don't think a lot of people take backups of their calendar